# Get only the Deepest paths from Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, path, directory

[image][image]

I need to JavaScript to get only the deepest paths from an array.

Input is an array of Paths
Expected Output: Only Deepest path

```
[
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\completion-provider.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\export",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\export\\global.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\export\\index.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\export\\local.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\index.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\module",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\module\\babel.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\module\\global.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\module\\index.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\module\\local.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\module\\webpack.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\main.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\package-configs.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\utils",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\utils\\filter-lookups-by-text.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\utils\\get-exports-from-prefix.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\utils\\get-module-from-prefix.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\utils\\internal-modules.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\utils\\lookup-alias.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\utils\\lookup-commonjs.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\utils\\path-helpers.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\utils\\regex-patterns.js"
]
```

here is another input sample

```
[
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\completion-provider.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\export\\global.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\export\\index.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\export\\local.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\index.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\module\\babel.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\module\\global.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\module\\index.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\module\\local.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\module\\webpack.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\main.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\package-configs.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\utils\\filter-lookups-by-text.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\utils\\get-exports-from-prefix.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\utils\\get-module-from-prefix.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\utils\\internal-modules.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\utils\\lookup-alias.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\utils\\lookup-commonjs.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\utils\\path-helpers.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\utils\\regex-patterns.js",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\package-lock.json",
  "D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\package.json"
]
```

Comment: Can you include those paths in this post?

Comment: That's the least that could be done for a coding request post.

Comment: Could you please ask the question with text code and image. instead of only image thank you

Comment: Come on, Wasim. You've been on the site long enough and accrued enough rep to know that questions that you haven't even attempted to solve yourself aren't going to work well here.

Comment: I don't understand why only those three would return.  There are other files of equal depth

Comment: 'Good question' is pushing it a bit as the OP doesn't explain exactly what criteria should be used which would result in those three specific directories being chosen. It can't even be accurately inferred.

Comment: At the very least it will most likely involve counting `\\` in the path for comparisons

Comment: everybody, I am really sorry, I always make those mistakes, not sure why. I have posted array. I am trying some code, I will post it here

Comment: @Taplar I will ignore renaming paths on same depth.

Comment: @rv7 I have put two samples, I have tried code which is not able to put here :) that's why I have not. Sorry

Comment: @WasimA. deepest path means the one with most number of `\\\` ? or something else...

Comment: @rv7 no its not with number of \\ , means look into all subdirectories and when its last directory, stack it,

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a path string to an item having parent and children:

```
const createItem = (path, parent) => ({
  children: [],
  path,
  parent,
});
```

Then sort the path strings so the root path of all other children will be first:

```
const sortedPaths = paths.slice().sort();
```

Then reduce the sorted path strings to a Map containing all items but having the children property filled with their actual children items:

```
sortedPaths
  .filter((path)=>!path.endsWith('.js'))//filter out js files
  .map((path) => [path, parentPath(path)])
  .slice(1) //remove first, it is root
  .reduce((map, [path, parentPath]) => {
    const parent = getParent(map, parentPath);
    const item = createItem(path, parent);
    parent.children.push(item);
    return map.set(path, item);
  }, new Map().set(sortedPaths[0], createItem(sortedPaths[0])))
```

You only need the rootNode though so you can do a `.get(sortedPaths[0])` on that map.

If you pass a root node to a function called `getLastDescendents` then this function can recursively check children and add only items that don't have children. Because you have nested items it will produce a multi dimensional array that you need to flatten:

```
const flatten = (arr) =>
  arr.reduce(
    (result, item) =>
      !Array.isArray(item)
        ? result.concat(item)
        : result.concat(flatten(item)),
    [],
  );
const getLastDescendents = (rootNode) => {
  const recur = (result, node) =>
    node.children.length === 0
      ? result.concat(node)
      : result.concat(
          node.children.map((node) => recur(result, node)),
        );

  return flatten(recur([], rootNode));
};
```

All together it'll look like this:

```js
const paths = [
  'D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib',
  'D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\completion-provider.js',
  'D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups',
  'D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\export',
  'D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\export\\global.js',
  'D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\export\\index.js',
  'D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\export\\local.js',
  'D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\index.js',
  'D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\module',
  'D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\module\\babel.js',
  'D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\module\\global.js',
  'D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\module\\index.js',
  'D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\module\\local.js',
  'D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\lookups\\module\\webpack.js',
  'D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\main.js',
  'D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\package-configs.js',
  'D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\utils',
  'D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\utils\\filter-lookups-by-text.js',
  'D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\utils\\get-exports-from-prefix.js',
  'D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\utils\\get-module-from-prefix.js',
  'D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\utils\\internal-modules.js',
  'D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\utils\\lookup-alias.js',
  'D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\utils\\lookup-commonjs.js',
  'D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\utils\\path-helpers.js',
  'D:\\Program Files\\atom\\.atom\\packages\\autocomplete-modules\\lib\\utils\\regex-patterns.js',
];
const sortedPaths = paths.slice().sort();
const parentPath = (path) =>
  path
    .split('\\')
    .slice(0, -1)
    .join('\\');
const getParent = (map, path) =>
  map.get(path) || getParent(map, parentPath(path));
const createItem = (path, parent) => ({
  children: [],
  path,
  parent,
});
const rootNode = sortedPaths
  .filter((path)=>!path.endsWith('.js'))//filter out js files
  .map((path) => [path, parentPath(path)])
  .slice(1) //remove first, it is root
  .reduce((map, [path, parentPath]) => {
    const parent = getParent(map, parentPath);
    const item = createItem(path, parent);
    parent.children.push(item);
    return map.set(path, item);
  }, new Map().set(sortedPaths[0], createItem(sortedPaths[0])))
  .get(sortedPaths[0]);
const flatten = (arr) =>
  arr.reduce(
    (result, item) =>
      !Array.isArray(item)
        ? result.concat(item)
        : result.concat(flatten(item)),
    [],
  );
const getLastDescendents = (rootNode) => {
  const recur = (result, node) =>
    node.children.length === 0
      ? result.concat(node)
      : result.concat(
          node.children.map((node) => recur(result, node)),
        );

  return flatten(recur([], rootNode));
};
console.log(
  getLastDescendents(rootNode).map((node) => node.path),
);
```

Comment: It has two problems, It didn't ignore path other paths at deepest level and it is not returning last longest path

Comment: In your image `need first ..` and `need those 3 paths`. That contradicts each other. To get the first longest just get the first index of the longest indexes or as you now state in your comment `last longest path` then take the last index. Are you trolling or do you have a legitimate question?

Comment: I am trying to make a project manager for Atom editor, I have added another image explaining my issue. I have already written a code but that work dead slow for large system files.

Comment: @WasimA. Updated the answer. It is important that all elements in the array share a common ancestor and that this is in the array.

Comment: It is returning deepest files, I was trying on deepest directories only, so If last directory has 10 files, I don't need 10 paths, I need only one of them. You are really some awesome developer, don't how you guys solve such a complex problem that fast, Whenever I meet developer like you I got disappointed about my skills :(

Comment: @WasimA. No need to feel that way. I see code every day that empresses me. You should almost be there but can remove the files from the array of path strings first. To identify a file it gets a bit tricky because directory names can end with `.js` as well but for now we assume that files end with `.js`. I have updated the answer with the filter.

Comment: @WasimA. If you still want to include the files in the nested nodes but would like to get only last directory descendants then you can do the following in the getLastDescendants function: `node.children.length === 0
      ? !node.path.endsWith('.js'):result.concat(node)?result : result.concat(node.children.map ...the rest of the code`